# SQL Triggers alternative in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a list attribute in a table which is a moving window. I wish to create a trigger in DynamoDb such that whenever something is appended to the list it shifts by one, dropping the earliest value. If I were using SQL, `create trigger` would've been my go to, but what about DynamoDb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS refers to it as a trigger in [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html).  Basically you write a Lambda function to do what you want.  However, in your example you would have to be careful not to create an infinite loop where DynamoDB is updated, Lambda is called and updates DynamoDB and then your Lambda is called again.  But [this post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-triggers-streams-lambda-cross-region-replication-app/) actually calls this design pattern a database trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamo DB doesn't have anything like SQL's "Before Update" trigger.

DDB's Stream functionality, while often referred to and used like an "After Update" trigger...isn't really at all like a real RDMS SQL trigger.

If you really must use DDB, then you're stuck with fronting DDB with your own API that implements the logic you require.

I suppose as suggested by another answer you might carefully implement a DDB "trigger" lambda.  But realize you're going to pay for 2 writes for every update instead of just 1.  In addition, let say you want you list to have the most recent 10 items.  Your apps would have to be prepared to see 11, or 12, or 13 sometimes.  Since the the "trigger" is async from the actual DB writes.